# What is the difference between writing emit in an event and not using emit?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, events, solidity

For example, `event CoinTransfer(address sender, address receiver, uint amount);`

What is the difference between `CoinTransfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);` and `emit CoinTransfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);`

Answer (score 1):

As of [Solidity 0.4.21](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#0421-2018-03-07), the `emit` keyword has been added to explicitly call events.